# Converting list of mixed class elements to data frame while preserving class

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a list like this:

```
list(
    structure(
        list(
            time = structure(
                1452841800, 
                class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
            ), 
            latitude = 34.0128987, 
            longitude = -84.7879747, 
            location = structure(
                list(), 
                .Names = character(0)
            ),
            day = "FRIDAY"
        ), 
        .Names = c("time", "latitude", "longitude", "location", "day")
    ), 
    structure(
        list(
            time = structure(
                1456875240, 
                class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
                ), 
            latitude = 35.85285882, 
            longitude = -78.69758511, 
            location = structure(
                list(
                    postcode = "27612"
                ), 
                .Names = "postcode"
            ), 
            day = "TUESDAY"
        ), 
        .Names = c("time", "latitude", "longitude", "location", "day")
    ), 
    structure(
        list(
            time = structure(
                1456621440, 
                class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
            ), 
            latitude = 33.81418132, 
            longitude = -84.73134873, 
            location = structure(
                list(
                    postcode = "30127"
                ), 
                .Names = "postcode"
            ), 
            day = "SATURDAY"
        ), 
        .Names = c("time", "latitude", "longitude", "location", "day")
    ), 
    structure(
        list(
            time = structure(
                1451953320, 
                class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
            ), 
            latitude = 33.6678031, 
            longitude = -86.5398931, 
            location = structure(
                list(
                    postcode = "35173"
                ), 
                .Names = "postcode"
            ), 
            day = "MONDAY"
        ), 
        .Names = c("time", "latitude", "longitude", "location", "day")
    ), 
    structure(
        list(
            time = structure(
                1452966960, 
                class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
            ), 
            latitude = 33.8458767, 
            longitude = -84.0986578, 
            location = structure(
                list(
                    postcode = "30047"
                ), 
                .Names = "postcode"
            ), 
            day = "SATURDAY"
        ), 
        .Names = c("time", "latitude", "longitude", "location", "day")
    ), 
    structure(
        list(
            time = structure(
                1455584160, 
                class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
            ), 
            latitude = 36.4001153, 
            longitude = -105.5727933, 
            location = structure(
                list(
                    postcode = "87571"
                ), 
                .Names = "postcode"
            ), 
            day = "MONDAY"
        ), 
        .Names = c("time", "latitude", "longitude", "location", "day")
    )
)
```

I want to turn into a data frame. I am almost getting there, but having some challenges. When I remove list elements that are not 'numeric', I get a nice data frame with numeric columns as follows:

```
df <- as.data.frame(
    do.call(rbind, lapply(d, function(x) unlist(x[-c(4, 5)]))),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ time     : num  1.45e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.45e+09 1.45e+09 ...
 $ latitude : num  34 35.9 33.8 33.7 33.8 ...
 $ longitude: num  -84.8 -78.7 -84.7 -86.5 -84.1 ...
```

So far so good...

Now, when I have a character item in the list, I get all columns coerced to character class. Not what I want. Of course, I can re-convert back. But...

```
df <- as.data.frame(
        do.call(rbind, lapply(d, function(x) unlist(x[-4]))),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ time     : chr  "1452841800" "1456875240" "1456621440" "1451953320" ...
 $ latitude : chr  "34.0128987" "35.85285882" "33.81418132" "33.6678031" ...
 $ longitude: chr  "-84.7879747" "-78.69758511" "-84.73134873" "-86.5398931" ...
 $ day      : chr  "FRIDAY" "TUESDAY" "SATURDAY" "MONDAY" ...
```

Lastly, because the `location$postcode` field has an empty list, this whole mechanism fails to even give me a proper data frame. I am working around it by extracting out that field separately, and column binding it as follows:

```
postcode <- sapply(d, function(x) if (length(x$location)) unlist(x$location) else NA)
df$postcode <- postcode
df
        time    latitude    longitude      day postcode
1 1452841800  34.0128987  -84.7879747   FRIDAY     <NA>
2 1456875240 35.85285882 -78.69758511  TUESDAY    27612
3 1456621440 33.81418132 -84.73134873 SATURDAY    30127
4 1451953320  33.6678031  -86.5398931   MONDAY    35173
5 1452966960  33.8458767  -84.0986578 SATURDAY    30047
6 1455584160  36.4001153 -105.5727933   MONDAY    87571
```

Three questions:

1) How do I preserve class while converting my list to data frame?

2) Is there a better way to handle null listed items within the list (my post code field)

3) If no other way on #2, is there a more efficient way to do what I am doing than one more loop through the data? I suppose I can combine the null list check on postcode field and concatenate within the `lapply` I am using with `do.call(rbind, ...)`

EDIT: For clarity, these are the classes of the named elements of my list:

```
sapply(d[[1]], class)
$time
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$latitude
[1] "numeric"

$longitude
[1] "numeric"

$location
[1] "list"

$day
[1] "character"
```

To the extent, the 'first' case works by keeping numeric values, that is still after converting my POSIXct element `time` to numeric. I would prefer it to stay intact. :)

Comment: See, also, `do.call(data.frame, c(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, .mapply(c, lapply(d, function(x) { x$location = if(!length(x$location$postcode)) NA else x$location$postcode; x }), NULL)))` to avoid coercions.

Comment: And, it is incredibly fast compared to anything else I tried above and beyond my original code. Can you write this up as an answer and I will accept it? Very nice...!

Answer (score 3):

Deal with `$location` by itself (circumvents the empty-list problem) and then use `as.data.frame` per list item (circumvents the everything-as-character problem).

```
d2 <- lapply(d, function(df) {
          as.data.frame(within(df, location <- if (length(location) > 0) location$postcode else NA),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      })
str(do.call(rbind, d2))
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ time     : POSIXct, format: "2016-01-14 23:10:00" "2016-03-01 15:34:00" "2016-02-27 17:04:00" ...
#  $ latitude : num  34 35.9 33.8 33.7 33.8 ...
#  $ longitude: num  -84.8 -78.7 -84.7 -86.5 -84.1 ...
#  $ location : chr  NA "27612" "30127" "35173" ...
#  $ day      : Factor w/ 4 levels "FRIDAY","TUESDAY",..: 1 2 3 4 3 4
```

**Edit**: as commented, the performance of the above is a bit dismal. This can be improved:

```
d3 <- lapply(d, function(df) {
             within(df, location <- if (length(location) > 0) location$postcode else NA)
      })
str(do.call(rbind.data.frame, c(d3, list(stringsAsFactors = FALSE))))
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ time     : num  1.45e+09 1.46e+09 1.46e+09 1.45e+09 1.45e+09 ...
#  $ latitude : num  34 35.9 33.8 33.7 33.8 ...
#  $ longitude: num  -84.8 -78.7 -84.7 -86.5 -84.1 ...
#  $ location : chr  NA "27612" "30127" "35173" ...
#  $ day      : chr  "FRIDAY" "TUESDAY" "SATURDAY" "MONDAY" ...
```

(Unfortunately, the `POSIX` class is lost in the process. This can be fixed with a call to `as.POSIXct`.)

The performance of the latter technique is a bit better, about 3-4x faster.

Comment: I like @rawr's use of `lengths` better, they're close otherwise.

Comment: It sure as heck is a very compact solution to my problem that solves for all the class problems. But, it is fairly slow because it is covering each list element to a data frame and row binding. Whereas, my original code is blazingly fast, but coerces the darn objects because of matrix conversion. Dang....I am not sure what to trade off here.

Comment: If you omit `as.data.frame` and replace `rbind` with `rbind.data.frame`, it will likely be faster but will be using factors instead of character for the last two columns. (This is easily fixed, of course.)

Comment: @Gopala what about `d <- lapply(d, function(x) {x[lengths(x) == 0L] <- NA; x}); data.table::rbindlist(d)` then? `location` looks like a list, so you would need to unlist it

Comment: I tried to stay away from data.table for 2 years. Time may be nearing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the data in the `$location` field need to be changed appropriately:

```
for(i in seq_along(d)) 
    d[[i]]$location = if(length((tmp <- d[[i]]$location$postcode))) tmp else NA_character_
```

Then, concatenate, in parallel, each sub-element of each element of `d` in the `Map(c, d[[1]], d[[2]], ...)` form using the handy `.mapply` version. Also -and at least for the implicit/explicit `class`es in this example- there is a `c` method available so no loss of `class` attribute happens:

```
ans = .mapply(c, d, NULL)
```

And convert to "data.frame" with appropriate "names":

```
ans = structure(ans, 
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = .set_row_names(length(ans[[1]])), 
                names = names(d[[1]]))
str(ans)
#'data.frame':   6 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ time     : POSIXct, format: "2016-01-15 09:10:00" "2016-03-02 01:34:00" "2016-02-28 03:04:00" "2016-01-05 02:22:00" ...
# $ latitude : num  34 35.9 33.8 33.7 33.8 ...
# $ longitude: num  -84.8 -78.7 -84.7 -86.5 -84.1 ...
# $ location : chr  NA "27612" "30127" "35173" ...
# $ day      : chr  "FRIDAY" "TUESDAY" "SATURDAY" "MONDAY" ...
```